# Remove custom postype base slug and prefix permalink with custom taxonomy + post title or just post title

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, permalinks, wordpress-rest-api

What I want to achieve seems pretty trivial still the solution is yet to be found:

I want to be able to avoid having the slug of the custom postype, (ie.  `article`) and have in the permalink the custom taxonomy's (ie. `site_topic`) and its term (ie. `blog`) or if not set avoid having it and have just the normal title.

What's been tried so far to change the permalink structure:
(it does work in the dashboard swapping links as needed but the pages when visited result in a 404, and yes permalinks have been flushed at each edit).

```
function ms_post_types_permalink_edit( $permalink, $post, $leavename ) {

  if ( in_array( $post->post_type, [ 'article', 'template' ] ) || 'publish' == $post->post_status ) {
    $terms = wp_get_object_terms( $post->ID, 'site_topic' );
    if( $terms ){
        return str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/' . $terms[0]->slug . '/', $permalink );
  }
    return str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $permalink );
}
 return str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/', $permalink );
}

add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'ms_post_types_permalink_edit', 10, 3 );
```

What we would like to achieve is a working permalink structure that works in both cases for these custom postypes while retaining the normal permalink structure for the rest of the postypes:

domain.com/custom-taxonomy-term/custom-post-title

domain.com/post-title

As a bonus the custom postype has the following in its registration:

```
....
'rewrite' => [
  'with_front' => false,
  'slug' => false,
]
....
```

What I also tried in combination with the above is both the following or a combination of them at once:

```
function ms_post_types_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule('article/([^/]*)/?$', 'index.php?article=$matches[1]', 'top');
    add_rewrite_rule('article/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$', 'index.php?site_topic=$matches[1]&article="$matches[2]', 'top');
}

add_action('init', 'ms_post_types_rewrite_rule');
```

and

```
function ms_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

  if ( ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
    return;
  }

  if ( 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
    return;
  }
  if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
    $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'article' ] );
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'ms_pre_get_posts' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code in your active themes `function.php` file

```
function remove_ra_slug( $post_link, $post, $leavename ) {

        $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'site_topic' );
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ){
        // get the first term
        $term = array_shift( $terms );

        if ( 'article' != $post->post_type || 'publish' != $post->post_status ) {
            return $post_link;
        }

        $post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/' . $terms->slug . '/', $post_link );
    }
        return $post_link;
    }
    add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'remove_ra_slug', 10, 3 );
```

Just removing the slug isn't enough. Right now, you'll get a 404 page because WordPress only expects posts and pages to behave this way. You'll also need to add the following:

```
function parse_ra_request( $query ) {

    if ( ! $query->is_main_query() || 2 != count( $query->query ) || ! isset( $query->query['page'] ) ) {
        return;
    }

    if ( ! empty( $query->query['name'] ) ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'article' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'parse_ra_request' );
```

Tested and works well

Comment: I got to this point of getting it to work too. It works for permalink structures like: `domain.com/post-title` but it doesn't when is prepended with the taxonomy term: `domain.com/custom-taxonomy-term/custom-post-title`

Comment: Please add above code in your active themes `function.php` file

Comment: Unfortunately, if I literally copy and paste the code it errors out as some of the custom posts don't have terms.

Comment: Still erroring `$post_link = str_replace( '/' . $post->post_type . '/', '/' . $terms->slug . '/', $post_link );` ... Anyway I wish that was the real problem as is simply solved by not passing the term in the permalink if it doesn't exist. But even with that it stills 404s whenever there is a term assigned.

Comment: please debug your code by `print_r` after every line so you will get what causing the issue